# Does this rhythm (dotted 8-16 8 8, hot po-ta-to) have a name?

Tags: terminology, rhythm

[image: rhythm in question, hot po-ta-to]

It is used in some earlier songs of Antònia Font:

If you slow it down it becomes a Phil Spector drumbeat.

In which other ways can it be precisely described?

regards

Comment: Looks like habanera.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That is called a [Habanera](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Habanera_%28music%29) rhythm (also known as Cuban contradanza). It is a traditionally Cuban/Afro-Latin rhythm. It is closely related to the [Tresillo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tresillo_%28rhythm%29) rhythm and the [Hemiola](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hemiola). It is the duple pulse correlative of the triple pulse Vertical Hemiola.

The Wikipedia articles go into good detail explaining these rhythms further, so I won't needlessly quote them. However, if you don't understand something in one of the articles, feel free to ask and we'll try to clarify it.

Comment: thanks, interesting connection with the other rhythms. I guess you could call the Tresillo and Hemiola diminished (by one note missing each) versions of the Habanera. Nicely answered!

Answer (score 0):

This rhythm (or rhythmic cell) is so common that it appears in everything from Opera to Reggaeton:

Reggaeton example: (Menealo)
https://itunes.apple.com/us/album/reggaeton!-20-latin-hits-very/id83091088

Opera example:
Carmen: l'amour est un oiseau...
https://itunes.apple.com/us/album/carmen-lamour-est-oiseau-rebelle/id454403092?i=454403701